# Alternate AddMonth functionality

Tags: c#

A person enters a date into the system, is there he selects February 28th, it reproduces march 28th. But my goal is to grab end of the month, March 31st. Is there a way to move to end of month for next month without incorporating the snippet below, in other words a cleaner method?

```
if (Date.Month == 2)
    Date.AddDays(31)
else if (Date.Month == 3)
    Date.AddDays(30)
```

etc...

any tips or suggestions would be great, clean code is always the best code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new DateTime(...);
var newDate = new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, 1).AddMonths(2).AddDays(-1);
```

this should also work:

```
var newDate = new DateTime(d.Year,1,31).AddMonths(d.Month-1);
```